# What is the nature of the Hollow Earth?

Tags: monsterverse

From the name, it would seem that the Hollow Earth is just the inside of the planet, which is how it seems to be portrayed in *Godzilla vs. Kong*, particularly with discussion of radiation from the Earth's core.

However, in *Monarch: Legacy of Monsters*, there seems to be some hints that the Hollow Earth is actually a completely different dimension: for instance, time passes differently there, and when Monarch and the military send Lee Shaw and others to the intermediate realm of Axis Mundi, they have to lure a Titan to open the passage rather than just lowering a ship or dropping a probe down the hole.

What is the nature of the Hollow Earth? Is it physically inside the Earth, or is it another dimension that happens to be accessed by going through holes in the ground, like some kind of kaiju Wonderland?